# Update markers on google maps on new wikimapia place request

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am newbie in android development and working on android application in which i am using google maps along with wikimapia request api. I am showing some buttons on the screen lets say Police, Hospital, Metro. When i click on the button let say "Police" it sends wikimapia request and the markers are displayed on the map,but when i click on "Hospital" it also shows me Hospital markers but along with Police markers. I have also used `clear()` of the map, but it clear the whole map. I need to show the markers on the screen on which i click and removes the other markers. My code is given below, please help me out here.

```
public class MyLocationActivity extends BaseActivity implements
OnMapClickListener, OnMapLongClickListener, NetworkStateReceiverListener{

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private Location lastLocation = null;
    private LocationClient mLocationClient;
    public AlertDialog alert;
    DocumentBuilder documentBuilder;
    Document document;
    private NetworkStateReceiver networkStateReceiver;
    boolean connectionStatus = false;
    final MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

    private static final LocationRequest REQUEST = LocationRequest.create()
            .setInterval(8000) // 5 seconds
            .setFastestInterval(16) // 16ms = 60fps
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        sActivityMyLocation = this;
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        sActivityMyLocation = null;

        mMap.clear();
        //unregisterReceiver(networkStateReceiver);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_location_hospitals);

        networkStateReceiver = new NetworkStateReceiver();
        networkStateReceiver.addListener(this);
        this.registerReceiver(networkStateReceiver, new IntentFilter(android.net.ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));

        ImageView imgHospital = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgHospital);

        imgHospital.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new PlacesAPICall().execute();
            }
        });

        ImageView imgPolice = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPolice);

        imgPolice.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                new PlacesAPICall().execute();



            }
        });

        ImageView imgMetro = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgMetro);

        imgMetro.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                new PlacesAPICall().execute();

            }
        });



        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        setUpMapIfNeeded();
        setUpLocationClientIfNeeded();
        mLocationClient.connect();


    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (mLocationClient != null) {
            mLocationClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        if (mMap == null) {
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            mMap.setOnMapClickListener(MyLocationActivity.this);

            if (mMap != null) {
                mMap.setOnMapClickListener(MyLocationActivity.this);
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                mMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
                mMap.setIndoorEnabled(true);
                mMap.setMapType(mMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                mMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    }

    private void setUpLocationClientIfNeeded() {
        if (mLocationClient == null) {
            mLocationClient = new LocationClient(getApplicationContext(),
                    connectionCallbacks, onConnectionFailedListener);
        }
    }

    ConnectionCallbacks connectionCallbacks = new ConnectionCallbacks() {

        @Override
        public void onDisconnected() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
            mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(REQUEST, locationListener);
        }
    };

    OnConnectionFailedListener onConnectionFailedListener = new OnConnectionFailedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {

        }
    };

    OnMyLocationChangeListener onMyLocationChangeListener = new OnMyLocationChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {

        }
    };

    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            float diff = 0;

            if (lastLocation != null) {
                diff = location.distanceTo(lastLocation);
            }

            if ((lastLocation == null) || (diff > 5)) {

                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),
                        location.getLongitude());

                CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition(latLng, 14,
                        45, 0);

                CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory
                        .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition);

                mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate, 25, null);

                mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
                mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
                //new PlacesAPICall().execute();

                lastLocation = location;
            }

        }
    };


    String urlString;

    class PlacesAPICall extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        JSONObject jObject;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            showLoadingDialog();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            BufferedReader reader = null;
            String key = "D###0545-58###39-6#####D-41####77-4#####8-###1C28-D524###7-#####4F5";
            String category = "287";// For the nearest medical related facilities. It could be a pharmacy,clinic hospital etc.
            if(isHospital == true){
//              urlString = "http://api.wikimapia.org/?key="+key+"&function=place.getnearest&q=&lat="+lastLocation.getLatitude()+"&lon="+lastLocation.getLongitude()+"&format=json&pack=&language=en&page=1&count=100&category="+category+"&categories_or=&categories_and=&distance=";//Hospital
                urlString = "http://api.wikimapia.org/?key="+key+"&function=place.search&q=&lat="+lastLocation.getLatitude()+"&lon="+lastLocation.getLongitude()+"&format=json&pack=&language=en&page=1&count=50&category=287&categories_or=&categories_and=&distance=";
            }else if(isMetro == true){
                urlString = "http://api.wikimapia.org/?key="+key+"&function=place.search&lat="+lastLocation.getLatitude()+"&lon="+lastLocation.getLongitude()+"&format=json&pack=&language=en&count=100&category="+44758;//Metro
            }else if(isPolice == true){
                urlString = "http://api.wikimapia.org/?key="+key+"&function=place.search&lat="+lastLocation.getLatitude()+"&lon="+lastLocation.getLongitude()+"&format=json&pack=&language=en&count=100&category="+670;// Police
            }


            if(connectionStatus){

            try {

                URL url = new URL(urlString);

                URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(
                        conn.getOutputStream());
                wr.flush();

                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        conn.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    // Append server response in string
                    sb.append(line + "");
                }

                String content = sb.toString();

                Logs.v(getLocalClassName(),
                        "Places API InBackgroung, Contect = " + content);

                try {
                    jObject = new JSONObject(content);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Logs.e("Exception", e.toString());
                }

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logs.v(getLocalClassName(), "Places API InBackgroung, Error = "
                        + ex.toString());
            }  finally {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }
            }
        }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            Bitmap bitmap = null;

            String icon = "", latitude = "", longitude = "",distance = "",place = "";

            if(connectionStatus==true){
                try {
                    //  JSONArray arrayOfPlaces = jObject.getJSONArray("results");
                        JSONArray arrayOfPlaces = jObject.getJSONArray("places");

                        for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfPlaces.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject jPlace = arrayOfPlaces.getJSONObject(i);

                            if (!jPlace.isNull("title")) {
                                place = jPlace.getString("title");
                            }
                            if (!jPlace.isNull("urlhtml")) {
                                icon = jPlace.getString("urlhtml");
                            }
                            if (!jPlace.isNull("id")) {
                                distance = jPlace.getString("id");
                            }
                            if (!jPlace.isNull("distance")) {
                                distance = jPlace.getString("distance");
                            }

                            longitude = jPlace.getJSONObject("location").getString("lon");
                            latitude = jPlace.getJSONObject("location").getString("lat");

                            double lat = Double.parseDouble(latitude);
                            double lng = Double.parseDouble(longitude);
                            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                            //mMap.clear();
                            // It clears the whole map
                            markerOptions.position(latLng);
                            markerOptions.title(place);

                            markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pin_x));
                            mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
                            mMap.addMarker(markerOptions).setSnippet("Distance "+distance);
                            mMap.addMarker(markerOptions).showInfoWindow();

                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                dismissLoadingDialog();
            }


            dismissLoadingDialog();
        }
    }

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: Hey Khan, I wish my answer is helpful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call mMap.clear(); in this method, so when you call this it will clear the map and then reassigned the markers.

```
 private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
            if (mMap == null) {

                mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
                mMap.clear();
                mMap.setOnMapClickListener(MyLocationActivity.this);

                if (mMap != null) {
                    mMap.setOnMapClickListener(MyLocationActivity.this);
                    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    mMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
                    mMap.setIndoorEnabled(true);
                    mMap.setMapType(mMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                    mMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
                }
            }
        }
```

In your click listener you should make your mMap equals to null, so it can make your above condition true in the method and will help you to clear the map and reassigning of the markers.

```
 ImageView imgPublicToilet = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPublicToilet);

        imgPublicToilet.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mMap = null;
                setUpMapIfNeeded();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should save the reference of your marker when you do `mMap.addMarker(markerOptions)`, and later do a `.remove()` operation on your marker.

so, it should looks something like...

```
private GoogleMap gMap;
private Marker myMarker;
....
....//where you add the marker
    myMarker = gMap.addMarker(marker);
    myMarker.showInfoWindow();
....
....//where you remove the marker
    myMarker.remove();
```